# ¿Cómo puedo saber el tiempo que una persona lleva trabajando pero solo en meses?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito saber los meses trabajados de los empleados o de algún empleado en específico.

Cabe mencionar que mi tabla se llama `VSS_PERSONAL_DATOS_CONTRATO`
y mis columnas `PERTRA_FECHA_INI` y `PERTRA_FECHA_FIN`

Esto es lo que llevo:

```
      select concat (p.vssper_apell1, ' ' ,p.vssper_apell2, ' ' ,p.vssper_nom) as 'Nombre del empleado', 
            p.vssper_fecnac ,
               p.vssper_nif ,
            p.vssper_nif_dc ,
            p.vssper_cod_tc2 ,
            p.vssper_fecalev ,
            p.vssper_fecha_cad, 
            pc.pertrab_fec_ini , 
            pc.pertrab_fec_fin ,
            
            P.VSSPER_EMP , p.vssper_cod ,pc.pertrab_emp, pc.pertrab_perso , 
                     case p.vssper_sexo
                              when '1'
                              then 'H'
                              when '2'
                              then 'M'
                              else 'indefinido'
                                          end as descsexo
                                                     
                              from
                                  vss_personal p
                              LEFT join vss_personal_datos_contrato pc 
                                   on p.vssper_emp =  pc.pertrab_emp
                                    left join
                                      vss_personal_datos_contrato pc
                                      on  p.vssper_cod =  pc.pertrab_perso
                                   
                                      where
                                        pc.pertrab_fec_ini ,pc.pertrab_fec_fin ,
                                         DATEDIFF(mm, '16/11/2012', '23/03/2020') 
                group by concat (p.vssper_apell1, ' ' ,p.vssper_apell2, ' ' ,p.vssper_nom);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y cual es el problema?

Comment: Por favor, usa minúsculas. Escribir todo en mayúsculas es como gritar.

Comment: Podrias incluir el resultado de esa consulta tambien?

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: ok disculpa ya no pondré mayúsculas no es la intención que parezca que grito

Comment: @SisDES, edita tu pregunta, por favor, y cambia el texto a minúsculas. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Vaya lío de query... ¿Podrías quitar de ella todo lo que no tenga que ver con tu pregunta?

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus comentarios es la primera vez que busco ayuda por internet , bueno la forma de preguntar en foros y tienen razon debo estructurar mi pregunta  para ello hechare un vistazo al manual para aprender de este sitio me resulto algo dificil de entender como funciona aqui pense que no habria problema el como preguntar , pero descuiden la formulare de nuevo

Answer (score -1):

Para ver la diferencia entre 2 fechas prueba a utilizar Datediff.
Te dejo un link para que puedas mirar la sintaxis

sintaxis:
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

Para más dudas sobre la función he sacado la información del siguiente enlace:
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15